# drag and drop from grid to grid in DHTMLX

Tags: javascript, xml, dhtmlx

I want to save the changes made in grids through drag and drop method without linking to server.When I refresh the window the changes made have to be saved to the grid.

I have loaded the grids with 2 different xml data and saved the id's of dragged text in local storage.

Comment: What is your question? Your last sentence seems as if you know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately such feature is not available without using of dataprocessor.
I may suggest you to serialize your grids, and store the serialized data in your local storage, so after the page reloads you will load data from the serialized XML:
[http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxgrid:grid_serialization](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxgrid%3agrid_serialization)

or you may move your dragged rows manually after the page reloads using the `moveRow()` method:
[http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxgrid:api_method_dhtmlxgridobject_moverow](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxgrid%3aapi_method_dhtmlxgridobject_moverow)